# How does shear-stress act on a spring hanging vertically with a mass attached to its end?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I have come to known that both longitudinal and shear strain act on a spring when it is hanging.
I can understand how longitudinal strain acts but I do not understand why shear stress/strain can act on the spring.

Comment: .any reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shear strain is due to the wire of the spring being under torsion (twist). The torsion arises because the force, *F*, due to the mass hanging from the spring acts  along the (vertical) axis of the spring, which runs through the centres of the turns (or radius *r*, say). This force therefore exerts a torque $Fr$ on the wire of the spring. The torque is countered by the torque due to the twisting of the wire.

Comment: Thanks it was helpful